# Parse MySQL result set and merge to collapsed array

Tags: php, sql-server

I have the following result set

```
ID SUBID DATA

1 0  Question1

1 1  Option1

1 2  Option2

2 0  Question1

2 1  Option1

2 2  Option2
...
```

I really want an array that looks like this

```
$item_data[1][1] = ID 1
$item_data[1][2] = Question1 <br> Option1 <br> Option2

$item_data[2][1] = ID 2
$item_data[2][2] = Question2 <br> Option1 <br> Option2
```

I have racked my brains trying loops within loops and string concatination but I just cant get my result set to look like this

Im trying to get it into one array so I can then out put the data - its important that the data stays together but different ID's are selerate from each other

SubID is not used - the table looks like this due to db design which I cant change

```
select iseg.item_id ,iseg.item_subid, iseg.item_data from items i
    inner join  item_data iseg on iseg.item_id = i.item_id
union all
select iseg.item_stg_id ,iseg.item_subid, iseg.item_data from items_stg i
    inner join  item_data_stg iseg on iseg.item_stg_id = i.item_stg_id
    order by iseg.item_id desc, iseg.item_subid
```

The Item data needs parsing in PHP first before concatination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `$resultset` is your mysql result set, you could do as follows:

```
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($resulset)) {
    if (!isset($arr[$row['ID']])) {
       $arr[$row['ID']][1]  = 'ID ' . $row['ID'];
       $arr[$row['ID']][2]  = 'Im data '.$row['ID'].' <br>';
    } else {
       $arr[$row['ID']][2] .= 'Im data '.$row['ID'].' <br>';
    } 
}
foreach ($arr as &$ar) { //remove last <br> from elements
    $ar[2] = substr($ar[2], 0, -4);
}

var_dump($arr); //to check the output
```

In your example there are only three rows for each ID, but my above code allows for any number of rows with same ID, so that could be important if that case could happen.

Comment: This works perfectly - was only missing a bracket on the if line

Comment: I'm glad it solved your problem, I will correct my answer with the typo you found :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
//adjust fetch method accordingly
$item_data = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
   if (!isset($item_data[$row->ID])) {
      $item_data[$row->ID] = array(1 => 'ID ' + $row->ID, 2 => '');
   }
   $item_data[$row->ID][2] .= ($item_data[$row->ID][2] ?
      ' <br> ' : '') . $row->DATA;
}
```

That should create the array as you have described, but it's a bit weird to me.  `SUBID` doesn't get used at all.

Comment: How do I get this to work with more than two rows? for item_data

Comment: It should work for an unlimited number of rows for `item_data` .. do you mean the second array element?

Comment: I mean what if I have more than 2 item data elements

Comment: @Rob I still don't understand why that's a problem .. maybe you can go into more detail about what you need?

Comment: Basically for ID 1 this forms an signle item so I need to concatinate this data together while its item one and store this in an array - then when it gets to item 2 it starts an new entry in the array keeping together item 2 - Sub id can vary in length meaning the item can have multiple parts - the end result should be an array with only as meny entries as there are distinct items

Comment: @Rob my method should already be doing this .. have you tried it out?  In what way is it incorrect?

Comment: I tried it but I got Array ( [] => Array ( [1] => 0 [2] => ) )

Answer (score 1):

You can also make the database return the data in a format that might be easier for you:

```
SELECT id, group_concat(data)
FROM my_table
GROUP BY id
```

will return you a row like this:

```
1      Im data 1,Im data 2,Im data 3
```

which may be easier for you to process.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume you have result in `$result` in php

Now you can have the data as follows :-

```
$i=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    //You can use SUBID.
    if($row['SUBID']==0) { 
        $i++;
        $item_data[$i][1]=$row['ID'];
        $item_data[$i][2]="";
    }

    $item_data[$i][2].+=$row['DATA']."<br>";
}
```

EDIT --- ---- 
I will suggest to use mysql power as @Alain Suggest in the answere [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12516719/1537696)

Comment: @Rob If `SUBID` is given in database table then `why not make the good use` of it?? 
And By looking at the table design, I can surely say that the ordering of the data is important and hence the database guy has put that extra ID there.

Comment: @ROB corrected the Error, and that was with - `$result = mysql_fetch_assoc()` Now corrected in answer it should be `mysql_fetch_assoc($result)`

Comment: thanks for the fix is the + sign correct ? - I removed the + however this dosnt not give me the result set im after

Comment: You did right by removing the + sign,
Just for sake, what query are you using?? and right now what perticular problem with the result of this example?

Comment: Please change the following in second last line: -
`$item_data[$i][2].+=$row['ID']."<br>";` -- to -- `$item_data[$i][2].=$row['DATA']."<br>";`

Comment: Im affraind it didnt concatinate the data field into one element

Comment: Have you corrected the `'ID'` into `'DATA'` in the line `10` (Now corrected in my answer)